# Is there a GetTriggerString() equivalent in the Windows Task Scheduler 2 interface?

Tags: windows, taskscheduler

The windows task scheduler interface v1 has a simple to use function:

`HRESULT IScheduledWorkItem::GetTriggerString(WORD iTrigger, LPWSTR *ppwszTrigger)`

Does the windows task scheduler interface v2 have something equivalent?

TIA!!